# Why do I receive a Parse Error code when trying to multiply two numbers?

Tags: google-sheets

In B1 I have 248.2.  In B5 I have -2.  I want to calculate the weight loss percentage.  However when I enter `=(B5/B1)x100` I receive a Parse Error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The multiplication sign in Google Sheets is the asterisk `*`, not any kind of cross symbol.